# Display text in an empty field group tab using custom code

Tags: 8, entities

I have created a field group with an empty tab. I would like to use custom code in a module to display something in this empty tab - it will just be a render array.

Can someone show me how this can be done or a link that might help me discover how to do this?

Comment: You can use `hook_form_alter`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding something like the below in hook_form_alter() works

```
<?php
    $group_name = 'group_some_name';
    $form['test'] = array(
      '#type' => 'container',
      'content' => array(
        '#markup' => 'test',
        '#prefix' => '<div>',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
      ),
    );
    $form['#group_children']['test'] = $group_name;
    $form['#fieldgroups'][$group_name]->children[] = 'test';
?>
```

Seems like I had to add wrap the content in `'#type' => 'container'` for it to work